# Error: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy

Tags: plot, pytorch, gpu

I want to plot these variables: prediction_py and y_test_py. But I got the error below:

[image]

Comment: Firstly,  please do not post screenshots as your text. Please copy and paste it as formatted code. Secondly, the answer for your question is in your screenshot as the recommended solution in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is on the GPU, you cannot directly convert it to Numpy array. You should first move it to the CPU and then convert it to Numpy array as such:

```
x = torch.randn(2, 3).cuda()
x_np = x.cpu().numpy()
```